# PHPUnit autoloader error: Class 'Yii' not found

Tags: yii, phpunit, composer-php, yii1.x

I am trying to start PHPUnit testing.

I am using composer to load PHPUnit 4.5 , Yii 1.1.14 and some custom Yii packages that we have built. 
Inside those custom packages, we autoload some files that set some aliases using the Yii class.

When running our application, we include the base Yii file manually, and then run the composer generated autoloads.

The trouble is, when we run PHPUnit.. the composer autoloads get run first. Even when specifying a bootstrap file with the include:

```
bin/phpunit --bootstrap carcass/phpunit.bootstrap.php
```

Leading to the following Exception:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Yii' not found
```

In fact it appears the autoloads are run even before the `--` options are parsed:

```
bin/phpunit --help
```

results in the same error. Removing the autoloads allows PHPunit to run.

Is there any way around this?

I tried placing an autoload for the Yii base file in our main composer.json, but the sub-packages' autoloads get run first.. same error.

I also tried placing an autoload for the Yii base file in each of the sub-packages.. but then we get redeclaration errors as composer uses `require`. I'm also not a massive fan of this option as it rigidly defines where the Yii definition comes from to sub-packages that don't really need to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the autoload classmap section is run first before all the files sections (including those from the sub-packages).

Placing the yii and YiiBase files in the classmap of the main composer.json for our project solved this issue:

```
"autoload": {  
    "classmap": [  
        "composer_packages/yiisoft/yii/framework/YiiBase.php",  
        "composer_packages/yiisoft/yii/framework/yii.php" 
    ], 
    "files": [ 
        ... 
    ] 
}
```